# How to detect platform using Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, platform

How to detect browser and mobileweb platform using Ionic 4 because when I tried with below code in desktop browser it is not falling in **‘core’** condition.

```
if (this.platform.is('core')) {
    alert('core platform');
  } else {
    alert('something else');
  }
```

When I have debug in chrome developer tool it showing **'android'** platform as per below snapshot.

[image]

Can anyone please help me how to detect platform in Ionic 4 or what can be the alternative for this?

Comment: Can you post complete code?

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar I have edited my question.

Comment: Desktop browser platform? Can you give an example?

Comment: I am trying to ask how to detect core OR browser platform using Ionic 4 ?

Answer (score 9):

For my use case I wanted something to distinguish between `native` and `browser` platforms. That is, is my app running in a browser or a native mobile device. Here's the service I came up with:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';


type CurrentPlatform = 'browser' | 'native';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrentPlatformService {

  private _currentPlatform: CurrentPlatform;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.setCurrentPlatform();
  }

  get currentPlatform() {
    return this._currentPlatform;
  }

  isNative() {
    return this._currentPlatform === 'native';
  }
  isBrowser() {
    return this._currentPlatform === 'browser';
  }

  private setCurrentPlatform() {
    // Are we on mobile platform? Yes if platform is ios or android, but not desktop or mobileweb, no otherwise
    if (
        this.platform.is('ios')
        || this.platform.is('android')
        && !( this.platform.is('desktop') || this.platform.is('mobileweb') ) ) {
      this._currentPlatform = 'mobile';
    } else {
      this._currentPlatform = 'browser';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between native and browsers? thank you

Comment: @M.Mariscal - when you run on browser it will give you the browser and when you run it on a device (android, ios), it will give you a native

Answer (score 7):

Currently Ionic 4 has support for platform detection. The following code works for me.

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
...
constructor(private platform: Platform) {}
...
ngOnInit() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.platform.is('android')) {
           console.log('android');
      } else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
           console.log('ios');
      } else {
           //fallback to browser APIs or
           console.log('The platform is not supported');
             }
      }}
```

Comment: How did you iimport it?

Comment: I have added the sample code, you can refer to the above.

Answer (score 5):

The following link may help you: 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-determine-if-browser-or-app/89149/16

or you can use the following method:

```
public isDesktop() {
    let platforms = this.plt.platforms();
    if(platforms[0] == "core" || platforms[0] == "mobileweb") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell me how can we detect  'mobileweb' platform in Ionic 4 ?

Comment: While debugging, I got  'android' platform in browser. I have updated my question with the snapshot.

Comment: You are connecting a android device and then debugging in inspect mode?

Comment: You should mention your code is for IONIC 3, and the link u provided leads to IONIC 3+4

Comment: How the hell do you import this in IONIC 4?

Answer (score 5):

Ionic-4 Platform specific value

goto- node_modules@ionic\angular\dist\providers\platform.d.ts

```
     Platform Name   | Description                        |
 * | android         | on a device running Android.       |
 * | cordova         | on a device running Cordova.       |
 * | ios             | on a device running iOS.           |
 * | ipad            | on an iPad device.                 |
 * | iphone          | on an iPhone device.               |
 * | phablet         | on a phablet device.               |
 * | tablet          | on a tablet device.                |
 * | electron        | in Electron on a desktop device.   |
 * | pwa             | as a PWA app.                      |
 * | mobile          | on a mobile device.                |
 * | desktop         | on a desktop device.               |
 * | hybrid          | is a cordova or capacitor app.     |
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic used by you is the correct logic.

The issue is with the ionic 4 and it is returning wrong values.

Bug has been posted on ionic repo:  https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15165

The other issue related to platform coming as ['android'] is also a bug and that has also been reported here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15051

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still struggling with this on ionic4/cordova, I solved it using

```
import {Device} from '@ionic-native/device/ngx'
```

Just add it into your app.modules and run this.device.platform wherever you need to find out, to give an idea, the output on web and apk from this simple code

```
console.log(this.platform.platforms());
console.log(this.device.platform);
```

is this:

```
Running on web (desktop and mobile)
["android", "phablet", "cordova", "mobile", "hybrid"]
browser

Running android local (apk)
["android", "cordova", "desktop", "hybrid"]
Android
```

Now I can correctly use the plugins for browser or mobile correctly, in my case is image loading and cropping.

A full explanation can be found at https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20171124-DetectingWhereIonicAppIsRunning.html

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the web platform you should use **[Bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser)** . I have used this in ionic 4 for detecting browser platform i.e whether it is safari or chrome.

Step 1 :  You need to install bowser in your project

```
npm install bowser@2.7.0 --save-exact
```

Step 2 : Then you need to import it in .ts page where you want to use it. let suppose **home.ts**

```
import Bowser from "bowser";
```

Step 3 : Then you need to write login to check browser platform inside a function in **home.ts**

```
checkBrowserPlatform() {
  const browser = Bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
  const browserName = browser.getBrowserName();
    console.log(browserName);
  }
```

By calling *checkBrowserPlatform()* you can know the current browser name.

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 4 / Capacitor**

I have written a service like so:

*detect-platform.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { find } from 'lodash';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DetectPlatformService {

    isDevice: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private platform: Platform, ) { }

    setPlatform(): void {

        const platforms: string[] = this.platform.platforms();
        const platform: string = find(platforms, (p: string) => {
            return p === 'capacitor';
        });

        this.isDevice = platform ? true : false;
    }   

}
```

**Note:** Since I use `Ionic 4/Capacitor` it gives `true` if it is on `device` else `false`.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:
First import

```
import {Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

// >> Then init the platform like this:

 private platform: Platform,

     if(this.platform.is('ios')==true){
        //ios PlatForm
        }else{
        //Android PlatForm
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ionic in Cordova, the most accurate way to get the platform is by getting the `cordova.platformId` from the `window Object`. Please check below:

- Declare the window outside your class component

  declare let window: any
- And then check the platform using the code below:

  // Desktop and mobile(iOs, Android, and windows) browser platform

  const isBrowserPlatform = window.cordova.platformId === 'browser'

  // iOS platform

  const isIOSPlatform = window.cordova.platformId === 'ios'

  // Android platform

  const isAndroidPlatform = window.cordova.platformId === 'android'