# Slot binding in tab Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

why isn't it possible to bind the slot property of ion-tab-bar?
I wanted to put my tab bar at the bottom only if the platform is mobile, but it doesn't work. Is there any work around?

My panel.page.html:

```
<ion-tab-bar [slot]="tabsPlacement">
      <ion-tab-button tab="foo">
        <ion-label>
          Foo
        </ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
      <ion-tab-button tab="bar">
        <ion-label>
          Bar
        </ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
```

My panel.page.ts file:

```
export class PanelPage implements OnInit {

  tabsPlacement: string = 'bottom';

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
  ) {
    if (!this.platform.is('mobile')) {
      this.tabsPlacement = 'top';
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Besides, question has little to do with platform detection. The core of the question regards to SLOTS, if they are bindable or if there is any work around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect platform using Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51816498/how-to-detect-platform-using-ionic-4)

Comment: You can't bind "slot" attribute dynamically. Can you try to achieve the same via *ngIf as first answer suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with using platform as there is a known issue in ionic 4 platform that it is returning wrong values.

The ugly work around is:

**panel.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs>      
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" *ngIf="!isApp">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab One</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>


  <ion-tab-bar slot="top" *ngIf="isApp">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab One</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

**panel.page.ts**

```
export class PanelPage implements OnInit{
  isApp:any;

  constructor() {
    this.isApp = (!document.URL.startsWith('http') || document.URL.startsWith('http://localhost:8080'));
    console.log(this.isApp);

  }

}
```